# How to check mime type of file uploaded image

Tags: php

I'm trying to check the mime type of an image.
This is my code:

```
    private function checkMIMEType() {
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $this->_dataArray['ext'] = array_search(
            $finfo->file($this->_dataArray['tmp_name']),
            $this->_mimeArray,
            true
        );
        if($this->_dataArray['ext']===false) {
            $this->error = "File not supported";
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This is the error:
Warning: require_once(classes/finfo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\XAMPP\htdocs

What I've got from now on is from this site: http://php.net/manual/en/class.finfo.php

And I think It's because I have a wrong version of the PHP because I wrote this online works with php > 5.3.0

Is there any way this code can run with a later version?
Or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: The file can't be found.  What is the `require` and what is the path to the file you show and `class.finfo.php`?

Comment: I have a class called init.php with this function: spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}); and I'm making my code OOP, so I have classes with different functions. But I don't have a class called Finfo, cause I thought this was made in the PHP 5.0.3 versions

Comment: Is that maybe the problem?

Comment: There should be a `extension=php_fileinfo.x` or similar in `php.ini` then restart webserver.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand you, do I need to add 'extension=php_fileinfo.x' to my code?

Comment: Yes, there is probably already one but preceded by a `;` which needs to be removed to uncomment it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me Abra, I was searching and found this"Windows users must include the bundled php_fileinfo.dll DLL file in php.ini to enable this extension." I think this is what you mean? But how can I find the php.ini?

Comment: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: Ok! I did remove the ; in the ini.php

Comment: Warning: require_once(classes/finfo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\WP3\login\core\init.php on line 29

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'classes/finfo.php' (include_path='.;D:\XAMPP\php\PEAR') in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\WP3\login\core\init.php on line 29   these are the errors I have now

Answer (score 0):

You're right on the money- this was introduced in PHP 5.3.0, so any older version will not have this class defined.

However, this class was a package before it was incorporated into PHP. You can get it from here: 
https://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just found out my current php version is version 5.5.19.

Comment: So, to clarify, you're running 5.5.19 and you're getting this no such file or directory error?

Comment: @Kim Could you run a <?php phpinfo(); ?> and see if it mentions anything about "Fileinfo" or "finfo"?

Comment: I did, this was what I found: fileinfo Ilia Alshanetsky, Pierre Alain Joye, Scott MacVicar, Derick Rethans